# Unable to consume POST method of OpenShift REST based API

Tags: c#, .net, api, openshift, redhat

I am trying to create application into OpenShift Red hat environment from my sample code which I have developed in C#.net.

```
string url =string.Format("https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domain/{0}/applications", cbDomains.Text);  

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);           
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(USERNAME, PASSWORD);            
        string postData = "{\"name\": \"myapp\","
                    + "\"cartridges\": [{"
                    + "\"cartridge\": \"diy-0.1\"}],"
                    + "\"scale\": false,"
                    + "\"gear_size\": \"small\"}";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);            
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;";            
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;            
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();            
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);            
        dataStream.Close();            
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();          
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();            
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);            
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

when I am executing above code I am getting following error:

> The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity.

on this below line:

```cs
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Please let me where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance Jyoti